# Return HttpResponseMessage in OData Action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I want return an anonymous type and for that i use HttpResponseMessage but the result is the code 406 Not Acceptable. This is my code

In WebApiConfig

```
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Groups>("Groups");
var getComplete = modelBuilder.Entity<Groups>().Collection.Action("GetComplete");
getComplete.Returns<HttpResponseMessage>();
```

In controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Queryable]
public HttpResponseMessage GetComplete(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,db.Groups.Select(c => new 
        {
            ID = c.ID,
            DocumentType= c.DocumentType,
            Name = c.Name ,               
            Debits = c.GroupMvtos.Sum(cm => cm.Debits) ?? 0,
            Credits = c.GroupMvtos.Sum(cm => cm.Credits) ?? 0
        }));            
}
```

With ApiController as Base Class using httpget Method works fine, but with EntitySetController in odata action doesn't.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OData actions cannot return anonymous objects. The type that the action returns has to be declared the service EDM model.

Comment: Then How I can return an Collection of anonymous object like in ApiController

Comment: OData collections are homogeneous and strongly typed. So, there is no way in the V3 protocol to return anonymous objects. Can you not declare a type and use that instead of an anonymous type?

Comment: I can't because I need the Queryable hability. I want let use $filter, $top etc in IQueryable<'a> and make just one call to the data base and doesn't make an extra step parsing the result to strongly typed. I would like just like the httpget method in ApiController where you can do that.

Comment: another answer that needs to be improved